# C# .NET Constructor for a pictureBox

Tags: c#, .net, constructor, picturebox

I am making a 2D Minecraft-like game just to occupy myself, but I have ran into a problem, I have a world generator, and now I need a way to render the blocks in the desired location. So I thought that I could just use a constructor like so:

```
public Block(int type, int x, int y)
    {
         this.type = type;
         this.x = x;
         this.y = y;
         /* Now I don't know how I would create the pictureBox :(
         Each pictureBox created with this needs to have a different picture (texture), 
         x & y coordinate, and name */
         //I need to make a block like this:
         Block blockname = new Block(1, 0, 0);  
}
```

I don't necessarily need the exact code, and a tutorial would be nice too :D!
Thanks in advance

Comment: I really don't understand the question.. what does "should do next" mean? Anyway, the next thing *I* would consider is to render or "paint" the output (eg all the tiles, after being added to some collection) as appropriate - don't use a picturebox/control for each tile, but rather paint the tiles directly into a single container. Initially, each block can be given a single solid color, say depending on the type.

Comment: What I meant by 'should do next' is that how would I create the new pictureBox.

Comment: `Each pictureBox created with this needs to have a different picture (texture)` Please keep in mind you only need 1 picture box. You can load the textures and map them to the appropriate location in the box. You'll wind up will a remarkably unplayable game if you try to load a picture box for each block.

Comment: @alstonp Thanks for telling me that :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me you are mixing logic with layout. You shouldn't do that in my opinion.

If you want to create the `PictureBox` control, you can simply do this:

```
PictureBox p = new PictureBox():
p.Image = yourImage;
p.Location = new Point(x, y);
form.Controls.Add(p);
```

This code needs a form and an image to work, but it will get you starred. I suggest to place this code in the form and iterate over the blocks.